# Hiding waiting when we use IFRAME

Tags: javascript, iframe

I use IFRAME in my site that open another site invisibly (ex: example.com), but there is a problem when a user open my site in the browser toolbar wrote "waiting for example.com". I want to remove the waiting message. What am I going to do? Thanks.

Comment: Well, I guess this is an explorer. If I'm not mistaken this is a built in behaviour of the browser and I don't think it is controllable by the html/javascript

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if you are trying to make a browser conceal what it is doing from the user, then you are doing something wrong (and there is a good chance it is outright evil).

Comment: If it's that important, consider using ajax to get the iframe content instead.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot hide that since your browser has made a request to example.com and your browser is waiting answer for that request!

Comment: and as @quentin said it is not fair to do things behind user's attention.